# Rails JSON Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm working on a Rails 4 API where the client can post data to the controller and it will save in a database. I was wondering how i could implement the user to POST nested JSON and then have the controller accept the attributes and create a model with them. The JSON would look something like

```
{
  'identifier': {
    'name': 'Test'
  }
}
```

Then in a private method i have

```
def parameters
    params.respond_to?(:permit) ?
        params.require(:picture).permit(:identifier) :
        params[:picture].slice(:identifier) rescue nil
  end
```

And when i try to access the 'name' parameter in my controller as `parameters[:identifier][:name]` i get undefined method []. Any suggestions?

Create Action

```
@picture = current_user.pictures.new(name: parameters[:identifier][:name])
```

Picture model only has `t.string :name`

Comment: Post the code for create action of your controller & also what fields you have in database i.e your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested JSON as long as you create them in your permitted parameters such as:

```
  def parameters
    params.respond_to?(:permit) ?
        params.require(:picture).permit(:identifier => [ :name ]) :
        params[:picture].slice(:identifier => [ :name ]) rescue nil
  end
```

This works on Rails 4 using Strong Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the JSON has the string `'identifier'` as a key whereas you are trying to access it with a symbol `:identifier`, which returns `nil`. So `[]` is not defined on `nil`. You should probably do `parameters["identifier"]["name"]`.